# sklearn (scikit-learn) logistic regression package —predict values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Logistic regression can help to predict a value whether it would happen or no. I'd like to know how can I do that using sklearn.

I'd like to know the probability if this event would happen or no.

I have a huge dataset (20K lines and 20 columns). To simplify work, I am using random data to understand how can I interpret data.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(100)*1000, 'B':np.random.rand(100)*100,  'C':np.random.rand(100)*10, 'target':np.random.rand(100)})

X= dataset.ix[:,['A','B','C']].values
y = dataset.ix[:,['target']].values

lr = linear_model.LogisticRegression()

lr.fit(X, y)

linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001)
```

Now should plot (lr.predict_proba) or what should I do in order to have probability of every line.

My data has 19 columns as predictors and last column as target (values between 0-10).

**UPDATE**

I got this as result of 
print lr.predict_proba(predictors)

```
[[  1.61122069e-02   1.47030433e-02   1.48213716e-02 ...,   8.08825797e-03
    6.50384553e-03   3.20953536e-03]
 [  3.91350489e-03   1.39936656e-03   3.53096458e-06 ...,   1.67332322e-02
    1.11458951e-02   6.44572229e-03]
 [  1.16547744e-02   7.98966288e-03   8.06262657e-05 ...,   9.72661281e-03
    8.09694771e-03   4.15593586e-03]
 ..., 
 [  1.26231837e-02   6.35868640e-03   3.20057785e-05 ...,   7.15622753e-03
    4.98867462e-03   1.95033329e-03]
 [  1.03813411e-02   2.30054537e-02   1.00700970e-02 ...,   8.68843317e-03
    1.25933032e-02   1.20899556e-02]
 [  2.76829605e-02   4.81774549e-03   3.62315829e-03 ...,   1.16611574e-03
    3.01633739e-04   2.84767806e-05]]
```

My question is : How can I find a probability of one row, based on the over-all information. 
I mean something like that :

```
Data[O]
A  B    C   Target  Probability_index  
1  22  33    0        1.03813411e-02
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `lr.predict_proba`, but you should consider using it on *new* data: Train your logistic regression on part of your data and predict on left out data. [Cross validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) will help. A classification report can be made using [`sklearn.metrics.classficiation_report`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)

Comment: @eickenberg: Based on your comment, when I plot lr.predict_proba(X[0]), I got an array. Does this represent the probability of success based on the first column. How can I predict values based on the over-all.

Comment: That is because you are trying to predict numerical values as targets. Try to predict labels. Start with two labels, `0` or `1`.

Comment: and how can I get the value of prediction probability of data['A','B','C'] together ? Can you show an example.

Comment: @eickenberg : I have done tests based on the comments you mentioned, can you please check the update.

Comment: Logistic regression is a classification model. You're trying to train it to predict real-valued outputs, which won't work. Use discrete target labels, as @eickenberg said.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems like you are trying to determine the probability of particular classes based on some of your data.  The logistic regresion predict_proba function will return a matrix with the probabilities of each of your classes. To determine which class each column corresponds to you should reference the classes_ variable within your logistic regression object.